# c++ get an string(serialized object) from ostream

Tags: c++, serialization, stream

I have an Image class which has the following implementation

```
friend std::ostream& operator << ( std::ostream &os,Image* &img);
```

So I can serialize it by calling

```
ostm << img; // which will write an string into the ostream.
```

Is it possible to get that string out of the ostream or serialize it directly into an string object?

Thanks!

The solutions worked like a charm. Thank you so much!

Comment: Do you really mean `Image* &img` ?  For output a `const Image&` would be more conventional.

Comment: Yes, that is what the original code says.

Comment: Please post complete code; it's not possible to debug your `operator<<` without being able to see its implementation.

Comment: I thought you said the original code used `const Image&` as the second parameter to `operator<<`? The code you have posted looks very suspect. Typically an `op<<` shouldn't have to create or modify objects being output. What's the definition of `Image`, the constructor that you are using and `cvSaveImage` ?

Comment: I find it hard to believe that `std::ostringstream` would cause a memory error unless you're feeding it masses of data. Can you show the definition of `Image`?

Comment: I figured that out; it's really stupid bug. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a `std::ostringstream`.

E.g.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>

std::string Serialize( const Image& img )
{
    std::ostringstream oss;

    if (!(oss << img))
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to serialize image");
    }

    return oss.str();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably your actual object is an `iostream`, or a `stringstream`. If an `iostream`, you can do this:

```
std::iostream ss;
ss << "Some text\nlol";
std::string all_of_it((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ss)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
std::cout << all_of_it; // Outputs: "Some text", then "lol" on a new line;
```

You need the `istreambuf_iterator`, hence the requirement for a bidirectional stream like `iostream`. Whenever you have extraction as well as insertion, you should use this, or a `stringstream` (or an `fstream` if working with files).

For a `stringstream`, just use its `.str()` member function to obtain its buffer as a `string`.